# Command line (Windows) to update same xml file with trim

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, xml

Currently I am using a `curl` command to grab data output to a text file and trim top 14 line away, convert the file to `abc.xml`

```
 @echo off

 call :sub >output.txt   

 exit /b

 :sub c:\curl -X GET server1 

 @echo off 

 more +14 output.txt > abc.xml
```

I would like to add `:sub2` to grab more data, but append to the same xml file rather than replace the content inside the `xml` file. Ideally, this would be done within the same `bat` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cmd knows additional redirection of the output that is appending the output to file X instead of overwriting X.
It is done the same was as on unix shells, using the '>>' redirection operator instead of '>'

In your case it would look like

```
call :sub2 > more_output.txt 
...
more ... more_output.txt >> abc.xml
```

Obviously, you have organize the content of output.txt and more_output.txt so that in the final xml opening and closing tags be in the right places.